# Incongruous backwards typedef syntax

Tags: c++, syntax, typedef, language-lawyer, c++98

So there I was reading about [the implementation of lambda calculus with template metaprograms](http://matt.might.net/articles/c++-template-meta-programming-with-lambda-calculus/), one proof of TMP's Turing-completeness.

As I was reading through the source code I stumbled on one (and then more) lines like the following :

```
template <int Name, typename Value, typename Env>
struct EnvLookup <Name, Binding<Name,Value,Env> > 
{
  Value typedef result ; // Line 84, what is this ?
} ;
```

I'm used to `typedef Type Alias;`, but `Type typedef Alias;` looks alien to me. And still it compiles fine with g++ 4.9.0 and good old `-std=c++98`.

I could not find any documentation on this syntax with Google, nor here on SO. Is this standard-compliant ? A g++ extension perhaps ? Will it blend ?

Comment: just like `const int i` and `int const i`

Comment: So this is standard-compliant, and in fact just a quirk in the language's grammar. Thank you ! I hope this question will be more search-friendly than the duplicate, if anything.

Comment: @Bathsheba to be honest I'm not that good at parsing grammars (seriously, without a side-to-side example it just skids off my brain). So I just trust the duplicate's accepted answer. Eh.

Comment: In C, you can even write just `typedef;`. The `int` type is implied and you don't have to give the `typedef` a name.

Comment: This language is mad and I love it.